# Is there a database out there for mapping verb tense to its base form?

Tags: english, verbs

Obviously, almost all the online dictionaries could map some verb forms like "spoke, spoken, speaking, speaks" to its base form "speak".

I've searched this on github but didn't find anything.

Is there an open/free database to do this job?

Comment: this process is called lemmatisation (because it takes a given form of a word and returns the citation form, or lemma). I don't know of solutions that are databases, but there are plenty of open source lemmatisers available

Comment: There are four principle parts or forms to verbs in English. Naturally, it's the irregular ones that can trip people up. s and ed and ing for regular verbs, and the rest you would have to cut and paste. A list is useful: https://www.thoughtco.com/principal-parts-of-irregular-verbs-a-to-g-1689681

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about a database necessarily, but you could use Stanford's [Stanza](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/) to do it yourself. [Here's an example.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xpFr-iKB4YXJrvW-8d7JjvbLKvfYM1Kh?usp=sharing) Notice the last code block:

```
doc = nlp("spoke spoken speaking speaks")
for word in doc.sentences[0].words:
  print(word.lemma)

# output: 
# speak
# speak
# speak
# speak
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, a question to which Wikidata Lexemes is *the* answer :)

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Lexeme:L380

Wikidata Lexemes is built exactly with this question in mind; however, it being a crowd-sourced tool, it might still be missing quite a bunch of verbs and/or forms, so... feel free to contribute!